# How to parse json array of arrays in jQuery or AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

Hi My Json Looks like below and i want to parse it to bind the data to array. Please provide me how i can parse it?

```
[
  {
    "ImgUrl": "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/DSC_7815.JPG",
    "CarouselImages": [
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7816.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7817.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7818.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7819.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7820.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7821.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7822.JPG"
    ],
    "VehicleId": 1
  },
  {
    "ImgUrl": "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/DSC_7816.JPG",
    "CarouselImages": [
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7816.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7817.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7818.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7819.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7820.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7821.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7822.JPG"
    ],
    "VehicleId": 2
  },
  {
    "ImgUrl": "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/DSC_7817.JPG",
    "CarouselImages": [
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7816.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7817.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7818.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7819.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7820.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7821.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7822.JPG"
    ],
    "VehicleId": 3
  },
  {
    "ImgUrl": "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/DSC_7818.JPG",
    "CarouselImages": [
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7816.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7817.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7818.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7819.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7820.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7821.JPG",
      "http://www.cowboysalamocityharley.com/used_bikes/th_DSC_7822.JPG"
    ],
    "VehicleId": 4
  }
]
```

is there any way i can parse it using an inbuilt library or shall i need to loop through?

Comment: What do you mean by parse?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json = eval("(" + result + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(data);
```